# Why jQuery code is always used in the Angular AfterViewInit method?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, lifecycle

I have been using the jQuery UI widget in the Angular application. I have seen on Stack Overflow that many experienced developers advise everyone to avoid using jQuery with Angular. Although I was able to make that widget compatible with the Angular application after a lot of hard work I have certain doubts in mind.

I see in many answers on Stack Overflow that we should use the widget initialization and other jQuery code inside the ngAfterViewInit() method. But even after looking at the definition of the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit), i.e.

> Lifecycle hook that is called after a component's view has been fully
> initialized.

Till now, I'm not able to understand why the jQuery code is being used in the ngAfterViewInit method. I was using the selectMenu jQuery UI widget and then to change the data of the dropdown list by clicking of a button, I initialized the widget in the ngAfterViewChecked() method. Although it worked successfully but I can't understand why it is working. So can anyone please shed a light on this topic and tell me why the jQuery code is usually put inside the ngAfterViewInit in Angular and when the ngAfterViewInit is checked?

Comment: hey, is there anything unclear about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Angular applies DOM changes as part of change detection. `NgAfterViewInit/Checked` is a lifecycle hook that signals the DOM rendering part of change detection for the current component is finished. Until then some DOM elements may not reflect the correct state of the component. Here is an example. If you have the following template:

```
<div class="list" *ngIf="value">...</div>
```

And the property `value` in the component class is `false` there will be no `div` element in the DOM. When you change the `value` to `true`, the DOM `div` element will only be added to the DOM during the consequent change detection cycle. It means that if, for example, you will try to locate that element in DOM before `NgAfterViewInit/Checked` using `jQuery`, you will not find it. The same basically applies to any DOM manipulation directive, like `ngFor` etc.

You can read more about DOM manipulation and change detection in these articles:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)
- [These 5 articles will make you an Angular Change Detection expert](https://blog.angularindepth.com/these-5-articles-will-make-you-an-angular-change-detection-expert-ed530d28930)